# Web камера Logitech и Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, камера, raspberry-pi, web-camera

Имеется камера Logitech C310 с заявленными характеристиками 720p 30fps.

При установке камеры на windows, запись полностью соответствует заявленным 720p 30fps - картинка четкая, сочная.

Есть задача подключить эту же камеру на OrangePI и сохранять на нём же видеофайлы, на апельсине установлен серверный Armbian.

Камера появляется в виде /dev/video0

При попытке зацепить видео ffmpeg'ом

```
sudo ffmpeg -f v4l2 -pixel_format yuyv422 -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 output.wmv
```

Получаю рассыпчатую картинку частотой 5фпс.
Возможность недостаточного количества ресурсов не рассматриваю - апельсин при помощи ffmpeg без проблем цепляет FullHd видео с IP-камеры, при этом параллельно занимаясь его обработкой.

Возможно я неправильно использую ffmpeg?
Подскажите пожалуйста, кто имеет опыт с Web камерами на линуксе ...

Заранее спасибо!

PS: конфигурация камеры по команде

```
v4l2-ctl --all --device=/dev/video0


Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : uvcvideo
        Card type     : UVC Camera (046d:081b)
        Bus info      : usb-1c1c000.usb-1
        Driver version: 4.14.18
        Capabilities  : 0x84200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps   : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 1280/720
        Pixel Format      : 'YUYV'
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 2560
        Size Image        : 1843200
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Default
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default
        Quantization      : Default
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 5.000 (5/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                       contrast (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=32 value=32
 white_balance_temperature_auto (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                           gain (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=64 value=192
           power_line_frequency (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2
      white_balance_temperature (int)    : min=0 max=10000 step=10 default=4000 value=4610 flags=inactive
                      sharpness (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=24 value=24
         backlight_compensation (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=0 value=0
                  exposure_auto (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
              exposure_absolute (int)    : min=1 max=10000 step=1 default=166 value=249 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority (bool)   : default=0 value=1
                      led1_mode (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
                 led1_frequency (int)    : min=0 max=131 step=1 default=0 value=0
```

Comment: Поставьте помощнее процессор, например, какой-нибудь x86.

Comment: учитывая что `Frames per second: 5.000 (5/1)`, то скорей всего ffmpeg'у будет достаточно задать правильный `-framerate`...

Answer (score 0):

> Получаю рассыпчатую картинку частотой 5фпс.

Лично у меня такое приключалось когда я неверно задавал формат пикселя во входном потоке. Разные форматы имеют разный размер и из-за это происходит "рассыпание" картинки.

Почему Вы решили, что Ваша камера выдаёт поток формата yuyv422 ? Вы уверены в этом?

Посмотрел *man* на *ffmpeg*, там нет вообще такого параметра: *pixel_format*. У меня - Ubuntu 42.3. Проверьте ещё раз.
Лично я так запускал *ffmeg*:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                              
# Захват изображения с камеры, посредством ffmpeg                                                         
# Изображение снимается с /dev/video0 и пишется в ttt.avi                                                 
# Записанный файл можно воспроизвести mplayer и totem                                                     

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0  -f alsa -i hw:0,0 -f avi ttt.avi
```

Кстати, в man написано про параметр -f :

> The format is normally auto detected for input files

Я бы начал с попытки захвата видео с помощью более "дружелюбных" программ:

mplayer перехватывает всё на свете, что только можно перехватить, без всяких параметров - тольк /dev/video0 надо указать.

gStreamer тоже универсальная штука. Попробуйте так:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                              
#                                                                                                         
# Захват видео с веб-камеры на хосте                                                                      
gst-launch-1.0 -v \                                                   
     v4l2src device=/dev/video0 !\                                                                         
     video/x-raw,framerate=15/1,width=640,height=480 !\                                                    
     xvimagesink
```

Ну а на самом первом шаге я бы попробовал запустить *totem* или любой другой плейер с GUI.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что ваш тест на формат потока валиден? И на заметку, большинство камер работают с форматами типа YUYV, а вот почему, читайте литературу.